# How can I return the ID of the Inserted Record in Entity Framework Generic Insert Method?

Tags: entity-framework, generics

Here is the generic insert method. I need your suggestion to return the ID of the inserted record.

```
public static void Create<T>(T entity) where T : class
{
    using (var context = new InformasoftEntities())
    {
        DbSet dbSet = context.Set<T>();
        dbSet.Add(entity);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: It should automatically be updated in your entity after calling `SaveChanges()`. In other words you don't need to return it.

Comment: All the tables has the PK with name "Id" and the type "int".

Comment: Test my solution. It works with all types of Entity ( has Auto ID or NOT)

Comment: Check this: https://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Multiple-ways-to-retrieve-Id-of-inserted-entity-using-Entity-framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a little modification:

1. You need to create an IHasAutoID that implemented by Entity

   ```cs
   public interface IHasAutoID {
       int getAutoId();
   }
   ```
2. In Entity Class

   ```
   public class EntityA : IHasAutoID {

       public int getAutoId() {
           return pk; // Return -1 If the entity has NO Auto ID
       }
   }
   ```
3. In your Create function

   ```cs
   public static int Create<T>(T entity) where T : class
   {
       using (var context = new InformasoftEntities())
       {
           DbSet dbSet = context.Set<T>();
           dbSet.Add(entity);
           context.SaveChanges();

           if (entity is IHasAutoID) {
               return ((IHasAutoID)entity).getAutoId();
           }
           return -1; // entity is NOT IHasAutoID)
       }
   }
   ```
4. NOTES:

   - If you are sure all tables have Auto ID with named "Id". You don't need to create Interface IHasAutoID. In Create function, after SaveChanges, You use REFLECTION to get value of Id property, but this way is not recommended!

Answer (score 2):

Arturo Martinex is correct in his comment.

Entity framework fixes up the ID's during SaveChanges so it's already updated in the entity you passed in to the method.

To do specifically what you ask you could change your generic constraint from class to a new abstract class that all your entities inherit, which defines the key in that class.

```
   public static int Create<T>(T entity) where T : BaseEntity
    {
        using (var context = new InformasoftEntities())
        {
            DbSet dbSet = context.Set<T>();
            dbSet.Add(entity);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return entity.Id;
        }
    }

public abstract class BaseEntity
{
   int Id { get; set;}
}
```

This technique is more useful in an `InsertOrUpdate` method

Another way to work with keys inside generic methods is to interrogate the MetaData as described here:

[The key to AddOrUpdate](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/05/03/the-key-to-addorupdate/)

Comment: This technique is the same my technique. Abstract class vs Interface.

Comment: Looks easier but I already went for Loc's solution. Thank you!!

Comment: You are assuming all entities has a key property named "Id"!

Answer (score -1):

```
public async Task<int> Add(TEntity entity)
{
 await _context.Set<TEntity>().AddAsync(entity);
 await Save();
 return Task.FromResult(entity).Id;
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Sorry, but this is a compilation of inaccuracies. 1. Entity Framework doesn't have a `Save` method. 2. A method with that name doesn't look like something that can be awaited. 3. No reason at all to use `Task.FromResult`. 4. Who says that `TEntity` has an `Id` property? Well, at least the compiler doesn't and that's the one in charge. The last error is enough to invalidate this answer.